# simple vbasic console serial receive/read raw binary data?

Tags: binary, serial-port

I have a very simple VBasic console program that reads raw binary input data from serial com port and writes it to the console window.

The problem is that it does not read all of the incoming bytes or it does not display all of them.

The code:

```
Module Module1

Private WithEvents SerialPort1 As New System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM3")

Sub main()

    SerialPort1.BaudRate = 31250
    SerialPort1.DataBits = 8
    SerialPort1.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)

    SerialPort1.Open()
    Console.ReadKey()
    SerialPort1.Close()
End Sub



Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
    Dim byteReceived As Byte = SerialPort1.ReadByte
    Console.Write(" " & Hex(byteReceived))
End Sub
End Module
```

So for example if I send a hex sequence 53 aa 55 bb to the serial port the console will write 53 aa and stop, then if I resend the message it shows 55 bb 53 and so on. So it's as if the program is not retrieving the data from the serial buffer fully.

Anyone have any idea what I'm missing or where the mistake is?

thanks!

Comment: It is because you read only one byte.  Use a `Do While SerialPort1.BytesToRead > 0` loop.

Comment: hi, thanks, ye I figured it out by experimenting.

updated the code:

While SerialPort1.BytesToRead > 0
    Dim byteReceived As Byte = SerialPort1.ReadByte
    Console.Write(" " & Hex(byteReceived))
End While